# React.map defined but says undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

UPDATE:

> by the way I'm already defined the data with the response in
>   `setState({ fetchedData: responseJSON.data })`

I’m just getting the response data in setState called `fetchedData: []` I’m wondering why I’m getting an error while I’m fetching `movies` from `this.state.fetchedData` even though if I did console log for  `this.state.fetchedData` I’m getting this data

```
{
"data":{
    "title": "The Basics - Networking",
    "description": "Your app fetched this from a remote endpoint!",
        "movies": [
          { "id": "1", "movieTitle": "Star Wars", …},
          { "id": "2", "movieTitle": "Back to the Future", …}
          { "id": "3", "movieTitle": "The Matrix", …}
          { "id": "4", "movieTitle": "Inception", …},
          { "id": "5", "movieTitle": "Interstellar", …}
        ]
   }
}
```

Also if I did console log for `this.state.fetchedData.movies` I’m getting response

```
[
          { "id": "1", "movieTitle": "Star Wars", …},
          { "id": "2", "movieTitle": "Back to the Future", …}
          { "id": "3", "movieTitle": "The Matrix", …}
          { "id": "4", "movieTitle": "Inception", …},
          { "id": "5", "movieTitle": "Interstellar", …}
]
```

I have tried to use map it doesn’t work here’s my code

```
const allNews = this.state.fetchedData.movies.map((data) =>
  <ul>
      <li key={data.id}>{data.total}</li>
  </ul>
);
```

> I’m getting error says  Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Then I did a big research I got I should use object.key here’s my code:

```
const getData = this.state.fetchedData.map((items, index) => {
    return (
        <ul key={index}>
            {Object.keys(items.movies).map((movie) => {
                return (
                    <li key={movie.id}>{key.movieTitle}</li>
                )
            })}
        </ul>
    )
});
```

I’m getting error says

> this.state.fetchedData.map is not a function

I really don’t know where’s my problem even though if I console log the Data I’m getting correct response

Thank you guys for helping me

Comment: The issue is with the way you are calling the map. According to the question above, `this.state.fetchedData.map` is not a function because `this.state.fetchedData` is an object and map can be run only on arrays.

Comment: Yes that's why I've tried to use Object.keys to covert it to object then I used map to covert it to array  but I got an error says I can't covert `this.state.fetchedData`

Comment: What does `this.state.fetchedData.movies[0]` give when you `console.log`?

Comment: @illiteratewriter I have tried to `console.log(this.state.fetchData.movies[0]);` I'm getting error **Cannot read property '0' of underfined**

Comment: try `this.state.fetchedData.movies[0]`

Comment: So weird If I `console.log(this.state.fetchData.movies);` I'm getting response like `>(5) [ {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...} ]`

Comment: @illiteratewriter yes I did  `console.log(this.state.fetchData.movies[0]);` getting undefined 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164372/discussion-between-illiteratewriter-and-laura-delgado).

Answer (score 0):

You are not traversing through your state correctly, this will solve your problem.

```
const allNews = this.state.fetchedData.data.movies.map((data) =>
  <ul>
      <li key={data.id}>{data.total}</li>
  </ul>
);
```

Comment: I’m getting error says Cannot read property 'movies' of undefined

Comment: by the way I'm already defined the data with the response in `setState({ fetchedData: responseJSON.data })`

Comment: if I just put movies in map. as I said above if I did `this.state.fetchData.movies.map` I'm getting an error  says Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

How is it that when printing `this.state.fetchedData.movies` you get `{ movies: [ ... ] }`? Going by the shape of `this.state.fetchedData` you should only get the array in `movies`, but are getting an object that has a `movies` key inside.

Have you tried `this.state.fetchedData.movies.movies.map`?
How is it that `this.state.fetchedData.movies` isn't only the movies array? If it's an object no surprise you can't call `map` on it.

When are you calling `setState({ fetchedData: responseJSON.data })`? When is `this.state.fetchedData.movies.map` called? How can you be sure the state is set with `fetchedData` in the initial render?

Comment: yes you're right there's a mistake in my question above I'm getting just  an array. I'm calling fetch function in another file and I'm using promise and then I'm importing it in my component using `componentWillMount` in the success response I'm doing `this.setState`

Comment: So the render method is still being called before the state is set, so there is nothing in `fetchedData` then. You should check for that before rendering.